# not aable to find the discrete fourier series coeffecients and plotting magnitude and phase

Tags: matlab

I have tried to debug this using unwrap but still giving error

```
% Fourier Series Calculation Discrete

No = 32; % number of samples
n = 0:No-1; % array representing the discrete-time from 0 to No-1
xn = [ones(1,5) zeros(1,23) ones(1,4)]; % Signal definition for one period

xr = zeros(1, No);

for r = 0:No-1
    xr(r+1) = (1/No)*(sum(xn.*exp(-1i*n*r*(2*pi/No))));
end

xr = round(1000 * xr) / 1000; % To avoid computational error

% Plotting
r = 0:No-1;
figure;

subplot(2,1,1);
stem(r, abs(xr), 'k'); % Use abs(xr) to plot the magnitude
ylabel('absXr');
xlabel('r');
title('Magnitude of Fourier Series Coefficients');

subplot(2,1,2);
stem(r, angle(xr), 'k');
ylabel('angleXr');
xlabel('r');
title('Phase of Fourier Series Coefficients');
```

this code is given an error:
Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.
stem(r, angle(xr), 'k');

Comment: Have you accidentally redefined angle and are shadowing the builtin function?